# trying to create a alert and outages widget for servicenow portal

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

How do I create a Alerts and outage widget in service now portal?

I need help with the code I tried to write the code but need help please.  I tried with javascript which is the preferred language for servicenow. So being that can someone please help me.